# iframe: how to scroll to a piece of text automatically after loading the page

Tags: iframe, scroll

I use **Flask** + **iframe** to make a website. I use iframe to show a google doc stored in another domain. The doc is very long, after loading the page which uses iframe to show the doc, I want the iframe to scroll to a piece of text which is unique in this doc. I can do this by ctrl+F+a piece of text, but, how to do it automatically after loading the page. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the doc is somehow displayed in html and you are able to change that html you can link to it via Javascript and the right selector (e.g. id)

Comment: Thanks. I use mammoth to convert the doc to HTML, but the converting is not very good. After I load the page, can I do a ctrl+F+text automatically?

Comment: use Javascript to access the Id ("id_prefix: a string to prepend to any generated IDs, such as those used by bookmarks, footnotes and endnotes. Defaults to an empty string.") https://pypi.org/project/mammoth/#mammoth-convert-to-html-fileobj-kwargs